# Git Clone - Python Forum

Tags: html, django, git-clone

I cloned https://spirit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html - awesome forum by the way. Because I want  to use it as a boilerplate to make my own forum... First thing is I want to find out how to replace everything that say's Spirit , with whatever I decide on my blog name. How Can I find in the cloned code where to replace 'Spirit' with my forum name - I have already ran the webpage locally and 'inspected' each part of the webpage that I want to replace with my own text/images.. I just cant trace back to the exact html/css/python/js file. Also , I am a newb, this is a common or "ok" thing to do correct - clone someones code and use it as a boiler for another project? I will give credit.

Comment: Do you want to create documentation for your own package? THen you may want to create your own documentation with this tutorial: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can grep for whatever content you are looking for in your project directory.  For example, to find all the instances of "spirit" in your project you can try:

```
grep -rwli <path to directory> -e 'spirit'
```

- `-r` will search recursively
- `-w` will search for a word
- `-l` will list the files the pattern occurs in
- `-i` will ignore the case
- `-e` provide a pattern to search for

To find the different options for grep just check the man page.

Then if you want to do a programmatic search and replace, you can pipe this search to `sed`. Here is an example:

```
grep -rwl </path/to/project/> -e 'spirit' | xargs -I '{}' sed -i -e 's/spirit/MySuperAwesomeForum/g' {}
```

This will replace all instances of `spirit` in every file in the directory `/path/to/project/` with `MySuperAwesomeForum`.  This can be a little risky however, since this may not take into account certain edge cases.  If you really want to go down this rabbit hole, you can research regular expressions for making an even more powerful search and replace.